# Filter Numpy Array for Values Greater than Preceding Value

Tags: python, numpy

Given the following array how can I filter to produce a new array that contains the values that are less than the next value by at least 3?

In other words, I need to compare each value with its neighbour on the right and add it to a new array if that neighbour is higher by 3 or more.

```
ex_arr = [1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 12, 16, 17, 23]

desired_arr = [3, 12, 17]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) to compare the successive values and form a boolean mask, add a `False` to this array (with [`np.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html)) to account for the last value and perform [boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```
ex_arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 12, 16, 17, 23])

desired_arr = ex_arr[np.r_[np.diff(ex_arr)>=3, False]]
```

Or using [`numpy.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html):

```
desired_arr = ex_arr[np.nonzero(np.diff(ex_arr)>=3)[0]]
```

Output: `array([ 3, 12, 17])`

Comment: How about `ex_arr[:-1][np.diff(ex_arr)>=3]`?

Comment: @KellyBundy it actually crossed my mind, not sure if slicing twice will impact speed. I'd expect `ex_arr[np.nonzero(np.diff(ex_arr)>=3)[0]]` to be quite efficient.

Comment: @KellyBundy here is a [comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epOfG.png), overall `nonzero` is the fastest. Double slicing might be interesting for tiny arrays, but the absolute running time is so small it's difficult to really compare.